# Security Auditing on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, security, tiger

The Tiger security auditing tool has been a standard install in the past.  However, it doesn't look like Tiger is being updated.

Is Tiger still a valid security auditing tool on Ubuntu 14.04.  If not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://www.nongnu.org/tiger/

"The 3.2.3 release was published in September 2008 and was mainly a bug fix release. This release incorporated all the fixes introduced in the Debian packages (a result of the help of users and developers using Tiger in that distribution), and included new features related to the handling of exotic filesystems in Linux."

2008 ... That's *centuries* ago in security so that makes the tool not really relevant.

I swear by OpenVAS for my *remote* security checks. For more information http://www.openvas.org/